# Why the cauchy is t distribution with 1 degree of freedom

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

> Cauchy: Place a spinner at (0,1) in the plane. Spin it in such a way
> that all angles are equally likely (uniformly distributed). The number
> that the spinner points to on the x axis follows the Cauchy
> distribution. This is the same as the T distribution with 1 degree of
> freedom.

I don't understand this paragraph.

I know the Student's t distribution is defined as follows: let $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $V \sim \chi^2(v)$. If Z and V are independent, then the distribution of

$$T=\frac{Z}{\sqrt{V/v}}$$ has the Student's t distribution with v degrees of freedom. I am wondering if the df is 1, then

$$T=\frac{Z}{ \sqrt{\chi^2(1)}}=\frac{Z}{Z}=1$$

Please point me where I am wrong.

Comment: The denominator is something independent of $Z$. It can't be the same as $Z$.

Comment: On the other hand if $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ have independent standard normal distributions then both $\frac{Z_1}{Z_2}$ and $\frac{Z_1}{|Z_2|}$ have Cauchy distributions